# JavaFx TreeView и ListView скрывать элементы

Tags: java, javafx

Как скрывать некоторые элементы TreeView и ListView?

Comment: Нужно реализовать поиск и я думал что будет разумно просто скрывать неподходящие элементы а не удалять их из списк

Comment: меняете у этих некоторых элементов свойство `visible` или `managed`

Comment: @Maxim ну я нашел только setVisible() но он скрывает сам элемент а не его итемы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27183526/treeview-java-fx-hide-a-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@FXML
ListView<String> localListView;
private Map<String, Boolean> localFilesMap = new HashMap<>();

// Скрыть элемент при нажатии
void initListView() {
    localListView.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        String selectedFile = localListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        localFilesMap.put(selectedFile, false);
    });
    refreshListView();
}

// Обновить ListView начениями из map
void refreshListView() {
    for (Map.Entry<String, Boolean> entry :localFilesMap.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue()) {
            localListView.getItems().add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```